# How to find out if one position of an array is empty? I am having the Error:invalid operands to binary

Tags: c

I do not do much C programming. I am trying to use the line

```
    if(strTable[key] ==NULL)
```

to find the position of the array that is empty.But it seems that it does not work. 
Can anyone tell me what might be the reason to this error? I think it might be that this is an address, but I don't know how to do it....

```
stringtable.h: In function `hasValue':
stringtable.h:32: error: invalid operands to binary ==
stringtable.h:37: error: invalid operands to binary !=
stringtable.h:39: error: invalid operands to binary !=
```

This is my code:

```
int hasValue(struct stringNode* strTable,char * s,int type)
{
   int key;
   struct stringNode currentNode;
   key = hash(s,type);
   if(strTable[key] == NULL) return 0;//line32
   currentNode = strTable[key];
   while(!(currentNode.content==s&&currentNode.datatype==type))
   {
      currentNode = strTable[currentNode.nextKey];
      if(currentNode) break;//line37
   }
   if(currentNode)//line39
      return 0;
   else
      return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to mark the questions as answered? Actually I do want to mark them, but seems that it is not directly on the page?

Comment: You can read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for that, specifically the entry that says "How do I ask questions here?"  That said, you might want to review the entire thing.

Comment: I get it. I did not mean to be mean....My mistake:(

Comment: @KeithThompson  Yes, I did not ask many questions before, and actually they all turned out to help me solve it. That is why I just marked them as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C arrays do not have "empty" elements.  Each element of an array has some value, and that value is of the declared element type of the array.

For example, given:

```
int arr[10] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
```

each element of `arr` has some particular `int` value.  There is no such thing as a "missing" or "empty" `int` value.

If you have an array of pointers, some elements can contain null pointers.  If your program logic treats a null pointer as "empty", that's perfectly reasonable.  (It's also reasonable to say that a null pointer is a valid value.)

In your case, you apparently have an array with elements of type `struct stringNode`.  We don't know what a `struct stringNode` looks like.  If there's some testable value of that type that your program logic can treat as "empty", you can use that.  If not, you're going to have to find some other way to indicate empty elements -- or restructure your program so it doesn't depend on marking some elements as empty.

Also, your error messages (thanks for posting those) indicate that your function *definition* is in `stringtable.h`, a header file.  Header files should only contain function *declarations*, like:

```
int hasValue(struct stringNode* strTable,char * s,int type);
```

The full definition should probably be in `stringtable.c`, which should have a `#include "stringtable.h"` directive.

There's more information about how to structure C source files, but it's beyond the scope of an answer to this question.  If your textbook is at all decent, it should expain it.

Answer (score 1):

That error string is normally followed by the operator that it's complaining about, which would be helpful information here.

Also, it would be handy if you somehow highlighted the line that the compiler is complaining about. The error output should include a source line number.

Comment: Yes, what I do here is to create an array of the struct stringNode. I tried to use: if(strTable[key] == NULL) return 0;
But this seems not the right way to do it, And I think the reason might be that it is actually an address, but if so, are there other options to do it?

Comment: I think your problem may be that you're passing in an arrray of stringNode structures, not an array of pointers to stringNode structures. You can't compare a stringNode structure against NULL, which is a pointer, you have to compare a pointer to a stringNode structure against NULL.

Comment: Side note... it's bad form to put code in a header file (.h).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `if(currentNode)` is legal, since `currentNode` is not number or pointer. Probably you should check `currentNode.nextKey` before of the assignment. (I don't know a lot about your code)

EDIT (after that you edited the question): What do you mean "Empty"? some member is 0? all members are 0? some unique value? For every possibility, you can check for it.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to do it if I want to find out if that position of the array is NULL?  And currentNode.nextKey is just an integer.

Comment: @KeithThompson , `strTable[key]` is a struct, so why is that compare correct?

Comment: @asaelr: It isn't; I wasn't paying enough attention.  Thanks.  I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @asaelr If I build an array of struct stringNode as struct stringNode* strTable[200], will strTable[1] be NULL or something else if I don't do anything? Thanks.

Comment: It may be everything. ("garbage")

Comment: My previous comment (now deleted) was incorrect; `if(strTable[key] == NULL) return 0;` is incorrect, since `strTable[key]` is not a pointer.    Repeating the remainder of the comment: Update your question to show us the diagnostic output from your compiler; copy-and-paste it, don't try to summarize it. For any line numbers it refers to, indicate those lines with comments in your code.

Comment: I see, so is there a way for me to find out if I have assigned any value to strTable[1] or not?

Comment: You can initialize that array when you create it (if it's arrays, to NULL. if not, to some value you decide), and then check if that position still equal to the initial value.